# What kind of deadlock the deadlock_timeout config parameter detects in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, deadlock, hibernate

My overall goal is to get a `40P01/ERRCODE_T_R_DEADLOCK_DETECTED` from postgres when an deadlock is detected. (To be more precise, I would like to get a LockAcquisitionException in Hibernate, which is the exception the `40P01/ERRCODE_T_R_DEADLOCK_DETECTED` error code is translated in [PostgreSQL81Dialect.java](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL81Dialect.java#L449)) I use Postgresql 9.6.

For this I thought I should set the `deadlock_timeout` and `log_lock_waits` config variables
as suggested by [19.12. Lock Management](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-locks.html#GUC-DEADLOCK-TIMEOUT)

> `deadlock_timeout` (integer) This is the amount of time, in
>   milliseconds, to wait on a lock before checking to see if there is a
>   deadlock condition. 
>   [...]
>   When `log_lock_waits` is set, this parameter also determines the length
>   of time to wait before a log message is issued about the lock wait. If
>   you are trying to investigate locking delays you might want to set a
>   shorter than normal `deadlock_timeout`.

I've set the following values in postgresql.conf

```
log_lock_waits = on         # log lock waits >= deadlock_timeout
deadlock_timeout = 5s
```

Now, when I create a deadlock situtation (from Java using Hibernate) I find the following in the postgresql.log

```
LOG:  process 17493 still waiting for ShareLock on transaction 322815 after 5000.464 ms
DETAIL:  Process holding the lock: 17495. Wait queue: 17493.
CONTEXT:  while updating tuple (132,35) in relation "publication"
```

However no `40P01/ERRCODE_T_R_DEADLOCK_DETECTED` error is generated (and sent to the JDBC driver).

I digged a little but into the postgres source code and found that the dead lock detection done by setting `deadlock_timeout/log_lock_waits` is a different mechanism than the one generating `40P01/ERRCODE_T_R_DEADLOCK_DETECTED`. The `deadlock_timeout` case is handled in  [backend/storage/lmgr/proc.c](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/9d4649ca49416111aee2c84b7e4441a0b7aa2fac/src/backend/storage/lmgr/proc.c) 
, while the `40P01/ERRCODE_T_R_DEADLOCK_DETECTED` case in [backend/storage/lmgr/deadlock.c](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/9d4649ca49416111aee2c84b7e4441a0b7aa2fac/src/backend/storage/lmgr/deadlock.c)

So, my questions are:

- Are these actually two different types of deadlocks that are detected?
- Is there a way to get an error when `deadlock_timeout` based deadlock detection happens?
- How can actually a `ERRCODE_T_R_DEADLOCK_DETECTED` error be forced to happen?

**UPDATE**: the code I use to get into the deadlock situation goes like this (Spring/Java):

```
// This is in a Transaction managed by spring
Publication p = em.find(Publication.class, id);
p.setComment("Outer "+new Date());
em.flush();

// This utility method runs the lambda expression in a new Transaction
// using Spring's TransactionTemplate and tries to update
// the same Publication that is about to be updated by the 
// "outer" transaction
Utils.runInSeparateTransaction(status -> {
    Publication p2 = em.find(p.getClass(), p.getMtid());
    p2.setComment("Inner "+new Date());
    return p2;
    // Would flush/commit after the return, but will "hang" instead.
    // Here I would expect the deadlock error but only get the
    // deadlock log.
};

// Outer transaction would commit at this point but will
```

Comment: How are you creating a deadlock situation? Postgres can only detect deadlocks happening inside Postgres.

Comment: Hi, I added a snippet of the code I use where I get the current deadlock situtation resulting in `process 17493 still waiting for ShareLock on transaction 322815 after 5000.464 ms`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A deadlock is a situation where multiple transactions conflict which each other in the locks they have cross-acquired. That situation is impossible to solve without aborting one of the transactions. The engine aborts such a transaction  with `ERRCODE_T_R_DEADLOCK_DETECTED` as the error.

The `log_lock_waits` is not primarily related to deadlocks, it's meant to alert about the situation that some queries are stuck waiting for locks, meaning that other transactions keep locks for too long.

> Are these actually two different types of deadlocks that are detected?

No. It seems you're confusing locks and deadlocks here.

> Is there a way to get an error when deadlock_timeout based deadlock detection happens?

It's automatic. If that error does not arise, it's because there is no deadlock.

> How can actually a ERRCODE_T_R_DEADLOCK_DETECTED error be forced to 
>   happen?

By creating an actual deadlock with at least two transactions conflicting. See [postgres deadlock without explicit locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042988/postgres-deadlock-without-explicit-locking) on S.O. for a simple example.

Comment: For "log_lock_waits must be smaller than deadlock_timeout", log_lck_waits is boolean.

Comment: @CodeFarmer: good catch, thanks. I've removed that paragraph, in retrospect it seems plainly incorrect.